# Cannot run a batch code as admin privilege

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using a batch code in removal Disk to install some software (from removal Disk).

My Problem is I need to run this batch code as administrator , but when I ran it as administrator it ran from `C:\Windows\system32` but my installer path is different.

This is a sample script :

```
Setup1.exe /S
Setup2.exe /S
```

Now how can I change the directory to installer path after run as admin

Comment: When elevating, Windows always sets the directory to `System32`. This is by design. Also, this is not a programming question. Ask on superuser instead - when you ask over there, make sure you provide relevant detail (remember, nobody can see your screen).

Comment: your comment is true but my installer are beside the batch  code (forexample `F:\sertup.exe`) and I use this command to `setup.exe /S` so directory must  change to  `F:\` So how to change it

Comment: Either add `@CD /D "%~dp0"` to the top of your batch script or prefix your setup file like this: `"%~dp0setup.exe" /S`.

Comment: Oh thanks ... This Solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

You can either add the following to the top of your batch script:

```
@CD /D "%~dp0"
```

…or prefix your setup file like this:

```
"%~dp0setup.exe" /S
```